# Redirecting child iframe to relative url, using js within iframe - but url is relative to the parent

Tags: javascript, url, iframe

Some interesting behavior that I didn't expect. I have a page which contains an iframe, and in that iframe there's a javascript function that redirects its own window.

I call the iframe's js function from the parent frame. My expected behavior is that it will redirect the iframe to a new page, relative to the iframe's existing location.

Instead, it gets redirected relative to the parent frame's location.

You can see a demo here:

http://thedailynathan.com/files/outlink/parent/parent.html

Am I doing something wrong here, or will I just have to code in an absolute url for my redirect?

Found this thread that sounds very similar. However no one came up iwth an answer for it:

[Using relative url for window.location in child iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280640/using-relative-url-for-window-location-in-child-iframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the:

```
document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.moveMe()
```

to:

```
document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.location = "javascript:moveMe()"
```

This way, the `moveMe` executed in the iframe's context.

Comment: Actually, a follow up syntax question. How would this work if I needed to pass arguments into moveMe()?

Comment: @Nathan Well, "javascript:moveMe()" is just a string, so probably you will be able to pass only string or numeric parameteres, like this:  "javascript:moveMe('myParameterValue')", "javascript:moveMe(123)"

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. Your solution definitely works for those cases, unfortunately I need to be able to pass some objects in. I guess I could serialize them if it comes down to it, but if there's a way to avoid that overhead that would be nicer.

Comment: @Nathan Well there is a little ugly way. You could set an global variable in the parent.html (winddow.myParam), and access it from the child.html when moveMe is called (parent.myParam).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, it works for me.

```
<script>function RedirectPage(){ document.getElementById("frame1").src = "http://WWW.microsoft.com";}</script>
```