# redircting page from link clicked inside of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to redirect my page to the original url in the iframe link. my site shares the same domain as the iframe links so when i use this script:

```
<script>
function replaceLoad(oIframe) {
  oIframe.onload = function () {
    location.href = '/?='+location.href+''
  }
}
</script>
```

I get duplicate urls on the redirect.

any insight would be awesome!

thanks.

Updated:

```
 <script>
 function replaceLoad(oIframe) {
  oIframe.onload = function () {
  document.getElementById("replaceLoad").contentWindow.location = "javascript:moveMe()"
   }
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an absolute link as opposed to a relative one?

That wouldn't be very helpful if it's imperative that the link is relative, but it should do the trick.

Comment: I may not understand correctly, but i am iframing auto generated data from a platform i am using so i do not have direct access to the iframes links. so what i was trying to do is write a script that gets the link in the iframe then redirects the parent page with that link

Comment: Okay, I had feared that may be the case.

Comment: Try this:

`code`document.getElementById("myframe").contentWindow.location = "javascript:moveMe()"

Comment: I feared you might say that. Been stuck on this for a while now keeping me up.

Comment: Do not threat - this seems to be the exact problem and solution you are asking after, if I'm not mistaken:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476431/redirecting-child-iframe-to-relative-url-using-js-within-iframe-but-url-is-re

Comment: It seems that because you are calling it from outside the script, it uses the path from outside the script as well. Hopefully that was the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Im not sure i"m implementing it properly

Comment: Could you chuck all the code your working with onto JSfiddle.net so I can have a clearer view of the problme?